# c#: How to change title of FolderBrowserDialog using P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, title, folderbrowserdialog

FolderBrowserDialog displayed a text "Browse For Folder" as the title.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297546/can-i-change-the-title-of-my-folderbrowserdialog) says that using P/Invoke we can do that. Whats that?
How to use P/Invoke for this?

Is there any other way also to change this?

Comment: Direct duplicate. Change the title of the question to reflect the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is no.  P/Invoke allows you to call native Windows API functions.  You can read an old, but still relevant article, about it here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Unfortunately, the specific function you would need to invoke [ShBrowseForFolder](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ShBrowseForFolder.html) does not allow you to specify different text for the window title.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we can change the caption of the folder browser dialog, if there is a way then its using complex p/Invoke calls.

I know there is a interesting [XBrowseForFolder - Wrapper for SHBrowseForFolder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/XBrowseForFolder.aspx?msg=2076008)  alternative available.

Its a vc++ component, you can use this component in your c# project with little coding effort from your side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing software for Windows 7 (and using .NET 3.5 SP1) then you can download and use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) which bring along a bunch of additional controls which may offer an alternative to the FolderBrowserDialog.

Here's what is included in the Windows API Code Pack

Windows 7 Taskbar

- Jump Lists, Icon Overlay, Progress Bar, Tabbed Thumbnails, and Thumbnail Toolbars

Windows Shell

- Windows 7 Libraries
- Windows Shell Search API support
- **Explorer Browser Control**
- A hierarchy of Shell Namespace entities
- Windows Shell property system
- Drag and Drop for Shell Objects
- Windows Vista and Windows 7 Common File Dialogs, including custom controls
- Known Folders and non-file system containers

DirectX

- Direct3D 11.0, Direct3D 10.1/10.0, DXGI 1.0/1.1, Direct2D 1.0, DirectWrite, Windows Imaging Component (WIC) APIs

Others

- Windows Vista and Windows 7 Task Dialogs
- Sensor Platform APIs
- Extended Linguistic Services APIs
- Power Management APIs
- Application Restart and Recovery APIs
- Network List Manager APIs
- Command Link control and System defined Shell icons

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the dialog box title. If you want that, you can consider using the commercial FolderBrowserDialog replacement component available in [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm)